# Одеть на лампу накидку или надеть на лампу накидку?

Tags: недопустимая-метка

Одеть на лампу накидку или надеть на лампу накидку?

Answer (score 1):

Что-то я сомневаюсь, что лампа это тот объект, в отношении которого можно употребить "одеть" или "надеть". Но в любом случае, если "на что", то **надевают**. Хотя в разговорном языке эти глаголы всё чаще смешивают, но это уже другой разговор...

А почему не накинуть? "набросить"?

Answer (score 1):

[**Запоминалки**](http://www.vbalashihe.ru/blog/user_post.php?id=924)

Одеть Надежду,

Надеть одежду.

---

«Одень», «надень»… Два слова

Мы путаем так бестолково!

Морозный выдался рассвет,

Оделся в шубу старый дед.

А шуба, стало быть, надета.

«Одень», «надень»… Давай глядеть:

Когда одеть и что надеть.

Я полагаю, что на деда

Три шубы может быть надето.

Но я не думаю, что дед

На шубу может быть надет!

---

P. S. "Набережные Невы одеты в гранит" (с).

Лампу - слишком прозрачный абажур - можно одеть в накидку или накидкой!

Answer (score 0):

Спор беспредметный. "Одевать" - страдательная форма (кого?), "надевать" - действительная форма (что? на кого?). Одевая человека, делаешь его одетым (в отличии от голого). Надеть же человека невозможно, ибо он - не одежда. Аналог: обуть - надеть обувь. Набуть невозможно.

Comment: *Одевать* не страдательная форма (ср. *одеваемый*, которую действительно можно назвать формой страдательного залога, например, здесь: *Мальчик, одеваемый мамой, смотрит на меня*). Вообще, не стоит использовать термины, если их значение не понятно.